# Wrong position of lables on x2-axis labels in gnuplot plots

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot the following data(which is stored in "0-time.txt")

time_,value

23:59:58,1

23:59:59,2

00:00:00,3

00:00:01,4

00:00:02,5

00:00:03,6

00:00:04,7

00:00:05,8

00:00:06,9

00:00:07,10

00:00:08,11

00:00:09,12

by the following gnuplot script:

```
set term png  size 800,600 

set output "0-time.png"

set datafile separator comma

set grid

set x2tics 6

set mx2tics 3

set link x2

set autoscale xfix

set autoscale x2fix

plot "0-time.txt" skip 1 every 2 using ($0*2):(0):xticlabels(int

($0*2)%6==0 ? stringcolumn(1):''), "" using ($0):2 axes x1y1 title columnheader(2)

set output
```

The output plot is alright except that labels on x2-axis is wrong. Please see the attached figure. How to correct it?[image]

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the figure with the script above until I changed `using ($0*2):(0):xticlabels` to `using ($0):(0):xticlabels`. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Gnuplot, the data index `$0` starts with zero, which is why you see 0 as the first x2 tic. But you can change the link in this way

```
set link x2 via x+1 inverse x-1
```

and then the x2 axis will be shifted by one unit with respect to x. Then you just change which x2 tics to display,

```
set x2tics 1, 6
```

which will hide 0, 6, 12, etc and show 1, 7, 13, etc instead.

Comment: I add `set mx2tics 2`, but it does not work. Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: my suspicion would be if you set tic labels via something like `0:2:xtic(2)` you can't set `mxtics`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

**Code:** (a bit cleaned up)

```
### special tics
reset session

$Data <<EOD
23:59:58,1
23:59:59,2
00:00:00,3
00:00:01,4
00:00:02,5
00:00:03,6
00:00:04,7
00:00:05,8
00:00:06,9
00:00:07,10
00:00:08,11
00:00:09,12
EOD

set term png  size 800,600 
set output "0-time.png"
set datafile separator comma
set grid
set xtics 2
set mxtics 3
set link x2
set x2tics
set autoscale xfix
set autoscale x2fix

plot \
   $Data using ($0*2):(NaN):xtic(int($0)%3==0?strcol(1):"") every 2 notitle, \
    "" using 0:2:x2tic(int($0+1)%6==1?strcol(2):"") w p pt 7 ps 2 lc rgb "red" notitle
set output
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. If I want mx2tics(for example 5), how to get it?

Comment: I assume you mean 5 x2tics, i.e. 6 subdivisions?! The line `set x2tics scale 0` makes the x2tics invisible, so replace the line by `set x2tics` and they will be all visible.